# linux DD disk backup - file smaller than disk?

Tags: linux, backup, hard-drive, dd

I got small problem. I need to make a mirror of a disk. Zero it and then restore data.

I'm using DD linux command to copy data to a file.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sde of=/media/Rozne-new/hitachi_disk2.img bs=1M
```

The problem is, Harddisk is 250GB big, and ooutput is 15GB file.

First partition is 14GB (according to disk utility).
All partitions on this disk are unmounted.

Comment: Did you get any errors after `dd` finished?

Comment: Even the best compression wouldn't have made this possible, which means, the image file is not complete.

Comment: No errors. just info: 
dd: reading `/dev/sde': Input/output error
3639+1 records in
3639+1 records out
15265935360 bytes (15 GB) copied, 568.663 s, 26.8 MB/s

Unelss, its an error...

Comment: Also, disk have 26 pending bad sectors. That's why i want to back it up, zero and see if it can still work.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not dd and linux specialist. more like intermediate ;).
So this seems line an error. If it is, is there any possibility to ignore it or smth? or display what kind of error is it?

Comment: @Ramhound, eh, that depends on what he has on the disk doesn't it? But dd does not compress so it's a moot point.

Comment: `dd` is probably not the best approach to this - `cpio`, `dump`, `tar` or any other similar utility will only store the files and directories, which is really what you want. `dd` stores all the free space, too, which is horribly wasteful if, for example, your drive is only 10% full...

Comment: To save space you might `dd if=/dev/sde [some other options] | gzip  >sde.img.gz`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To ignore read errors do this:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sde of=/media/Rozne-new/hitachi_disk2.img bs=1M conv=noerror
```

To see all the options available to you type this:

```
dd --help
```

Comment: Shouldn't `noerror` be `conv=noerror`?

Comment: @palacsint - you are absolutely correct. I've corrected my answer, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

If you have bad blocks you could try [`dd_rescue`](http://www.garloff.de/kurt/linux/ddrescue/):

> - dd_rescue does not abort on errors on the input file, unless you specify a maximum error number. Then dd_rescue will abort when this number is reached.
> - It uses two block sizes, a large (soft) block size and a small (hard) block size. In case of errors, the size falls back to the small one and is promoted again after a while without errors.

Be careful with `dd`:

- If there is a small error inside a bigger block, it skips the subsequent sectors from that block. So, if only the first 512-byte sector is unreadable in a 1 megabyte block you lost 1 megabyte of data.
- Without `conv=sync` it skips the unreadable and subsequent sectors from the erroneous
  blocks (instead of writing out zeros) which shifts the remaining blocks and could cause further filesystem damage.

Reference: [Disk drive recovery: ddrescue, dd_rescue, dd_rhelp, by John Gilmore](http://ubuntu-rescue-remix.org/node/51)

Comment: Or [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html).

Comment: @Karan: Thanks for the hint! I think you should write it as an asnwer. I'd upvote that too.

Comment: Thanks, but it was just an add-on to your answer, so if you want feel free to incorporate it. :) I agree with John Gilmore though - as per my own experience ddrescue was better at retrieving data from a dying drive as compared to dd_rescue.